# fscanf with overlapped delimiter

Tags: c, linux, scanf, delimiter

I have unfamiliar issues of fscanf delimiter on C.

The data.txt is below.

```
k:01062003200:0222005000:G5
g:01034567800::G7
n:01068003200:0222000000:G6
m:01023450987::
```

As you can see, it is not always that data are written between delimiters `':'`
but I have to load it anyway even it's `""`.

`fscanf(fileName, "%[^:]:%[^:]:%[^:]:%s", name, phone1, phone2, memo)`

This is my code only worked well with a line that no blank between delimiters.

How can I load them all?

Comment: It (`strsep`) is non-standard, but `strtok` cannot handle "empty" fields.

Comment: Did it work as well as you thought? In a loop, I would expect it to capture a newline at the start of line 2 onward, because format `%[]` does not filter the newline left by the previous final `%s`. Add a space before the first one, as `" %[^:] ..."` to filter that newline. Please see [scanf() leaves the newline char in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-the-buffer). P.S. always check the return value from `scanf` function family.

Comment: ... are you sure that was your exact code? I would not expect to see `fscanf(fileName,  ...)` but a variable named more like a file pointer than its name. So I wonder if there was anything else different. You have not yet read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) or how to post the [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the shortest **complete** code that shows the problem.

Comment: `fgets` and `strsep` worked well !
Thanks ! :)